# Problema con javascript en visual studio

Tags: javascript, html

Resulta que tengo una función en Javascript que formatea un numero ingresado en una caja de texto, ejemplo: si ingreso 1324, me lo formatea a $1.234(formato peso Chile). Todo lo anterior funciona muy bien, pero en el editor sublime. Yo trabajo en Visual Studio 2012 y al copiar el mismo código sobre éste me arroja un error de sintaxis, como se muestra en la imagen.
Alguien me podrá ayudar a corregir ese error por favor?

[image: problema de sintaxis]

Comment: el código que yo leo es funcional, seguramente esos errores se deban a que no tiene algún plugin que ayude a entender la sintáxis de ES en especial la versión 6 como veo que usas

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que tu IDE no soporta sintaxis Javascript. Puedes usar un plugin para solucionar esto. Ve a Herramientas/Extensiones y Actualizaciones, en la pestaña 'En linea' puedes encontrar plugins Javascript.
O también puedes descargarlo desde [aquí](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.JavaScriptSnippetPack) e instalarlo manualmente